# Strapi on Heroku Deploy very delayed http request

Tags: mongodb, http, heroku, strapi, mongodb-atlas

I have been working with using Strapi as my backend service and connecting it to my MongoDB Atlas instance and it is running and works. However, when I make http requests from my front-end, it takes up to 12 seconds to retrieve the response. My response is a very small JSON response (array of 3 objects with only 5 properties). However, it seems when I log into the admin portal and force the Strapi app to run, the requests are instant. I understand this may be an issue with the dynos cycling, but what solutions are there to this?

Answer (score 0):

The reason you have this because of Heroku dynos basically turn-off after 30mins of inactivity. So next time when you ping the server/API, it takes some time to start again. The easiest way to go around is, have the Heroku service being pinged every x intervals (can be hour/day).

You can use services like this (http://easycron.com/) to set up a CRON to ping the Heroku service.

Hope it helps :)